Как записать что то в центр файла в питоне?
Предположим что есть файл с некой информацией. При выполнении условия, нужно записать в файл в конкретном место ФИО, это возможно сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

"Промотать" до нужной позиции, запомнить ее, считать весь "хвост" файла в память, вернуться на позицию вставки, записать, дописать дальше хвост. Либо более простой вариант - считать весь файл в память, работать с его содержимым как со строкой, потом целиком записать обратно в файл.
